# Passing props.color on inline style - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass a color to my text, but it's not applying. If I change to Card.props.color, it works, but the parameter props is never read.

```
const Card = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
           <p style={{color: props.color}}>Random text</p> 
        </div>
    )
}

Card.props = {
    color: 'blue'
}


export default Card
```

Comment: Why are you defining `Card.props` after your define the component `Card`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the default props

```js
const Card = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
           <p style={{color: props.color}}>Random text</p> 
        </div>
    )
}

Card.defaultProps = {
    color: 'blue'
}


export default Card
```

Answer (score 2):

you should not write this code as this is mutating the props object that react use.

```
Card.props = {color : 'blue'}
```

for proper usage the props are passed where you would be using the Card component

```
<Card color=  {"blue"} />
```

Comment: Or even just `<Card color="blue" />` would work

Answer (score 1):

You can assign your default prop values to the [defaultProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#default-prop-values) property or even better take advantage of the [default function parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) since your component is a function.

```
const Card = ({ color = 'blue' }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p style={{ color }}>Random text</p> 
    </div>
  )
}

export default Card;
```